# As a number (base 10) approaches infinity, what would be longer? Represented in BCD or Base-2?

Tags: base-conversion, binary

My professor asked this question in his lecture class and I can't figure out the answer.

My guess is BCD because you can't use up all the numbers (10 to 15), so you eat up space?

Comment: So why do you think this might not be the answer? Did you try, for example, writing down formulas for the length of the number $n$ in BCD and in binary, and comparing those lengths?

Comment: I know that the length of the number in BCD is the NumOfDigits * 4. In Binary, it follows the highest power of 2 (ex. 126 is less than 128 (2^7) so it has 7 bits).

Comment: I tried large numbers as well, ex: 3 850 000 in binary is 11 1010 1011 1111 0001 0000 (22 bits) vs. (7 digits * 4) = 28 bits in BCD.

Comment: Additionally, a number like 123,456,789 in binary has 27 digits. And has 36 in BCD. The trend shows that BCD is always longer, but I'm unsure if I can generalize that.

Comment: You generalize it by writing down formulas for the numbers of bits (think in terms of logarithms) and comparing the two formulas.